File upload to SharePoint is not working and is not throwing any errors
I've to upload file on sharepoint location inside particular folder, and for that I've added below line of code,
public async Task UploadFileAsync(string siteId, string driveId, string folderId, string fileName, byte[] fileContent, string accessToken)
{
    HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

    try
    {
         var requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/items/{folderId}:/{fileName}:/content";


        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(fileContent))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(requestUrl, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to upload file. Status: {response.StatusCode}, Error: {await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

But this code does not work for me, even though it does not throw any errors. When I debug the code, it stops at the following line:
var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(requestUrl, content);
I've assigned the below permission :

Can anyone please help me on this.

Also, I forgot to mention one point: I used the same location to fetch the file using the SiteId, DriveId, and FolderId, and the same IDs used to upload the file.

You can [edit] your question to add this information.

You could possibly try using StreamContent. Otherwise, you might check the response.Content for the successful messages to see if you're maybe getting back a 204 No Content or some other message from the API.

@PoojaParmar what is the file size? For files larger than 4 MB, use a session-based upload

The file size is 150KB only.

@ZachA, The problem is that we're not getting a response from the line "await _httpClient.PutAsync(requestUrl, content);". The project stops working without throwing any errors.

@PoojaParmar, That is very strange. I wouldn't suspect this code would deadlock. You might try giving the Put method a cancellation token on a shorter timer. If the task cancels and the program proceeds, then there's no deadlock and the problem could likely be in your network rather than your code. You may also want to make your HttpClient either static or injected, new clients can lead to port exhaustion: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

The issue has been resolved. The problem was caused by adding an await operation, which led to task cancellation

The issue has been resolved. The problem was caused by adding an await operation, which caused the task to be canceled.
Here is the line of code :
var response = _httpClient.PutAsync(requestUrl, content);

Not awaiting an async task is not a good fix. It sounds like you might be running into a dispatcher issue. Are you using WPF or WinForms, or anything with a dedicated UI thread? You may need to dispatch the task to avoid the deadlock: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html
